# Will apple reject my app for telling that they can register to the site?

Tags: ios, app-store

I got my app rejected because it had a registration form that required too much information that the app never used. The simplest solution would be be to remove the registration and just let the user login inside the app (it can also be used without login but with less functionalities). What I was thinking was to remove the registration button and just add an `UILabel` where I tell the users that if they want to register they can visit the site (I won't provide a link for registration).

Does anyone know if my app is going to get rejected again just for telling the user to register on the site?

This is the reason Apple review team gave me:

> 17.2 Details
>
> We noticed that your app requires users to register with personal
>   information. Apps cannot require users to enter personal information
>   that is not relevant to the app features.
>
> We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

The screenshot was of the registration form that required some informations that weren't used inside the app.

Comment: post what they exactly told?

Comment: @Spynet I've added their message

Comment: Why are you asking for that information if it is never used? Maybe just don't ask that information in the registration process

Comment: @Popeye There are some minor information that we don't need (date of birth for example) and we're going to take them out but most of them are relevant, for example the registration requires where the user lives, this because the app shows a list of products that are nearby and that the user can order. But I don't know if Apple will accept this kind of explanation and since we need the app to be published I was searching for the easier solution

Comment: @Signo why are you asking for DOB when you don't need it. I'd be looking at removing that if there is no reason for it and any other field that you have that you don't use. As for where the user lives, I'd say a better solution would be to get the users location at the time of using the app and then drop the location on the floor when finished with it.

Comment: @Popeye Yeah I know but we used the same registration form the site used without worrying the amount of information asked. We'll obviously going to change it now that we know about this problem

Comment: @Signo You need to be asking whoever designed your registration process why they asked for DOB and maybe ask other fields as well and decide if they are needed or even being used if they aren't drop them, you are just creating more fields for a user to fill in that will never be used. I'd probably revisit the whole registration process and ask do we really even need users to register and log in for anything. Are we taking any valuable information that needs protecting if not why even have a login.

Comment: @Popeye Yes that would be the best solution, mostly because less information required means more users, but I'm pretty sure the client won't change his website and DB just because the app requires less information.  In the next release we'll try to have a light-registration form with just few information required by the app and see how it works

Comment: Hi this may be usefull for you https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message in App Store Review Guidlines is quite clear:

> Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected

which, of course does not stop you from asking for it while letting the user register, however - you **MUST** have a good reason for it, like:

> Apps may ask for date of birth (or use other age-gating mechanisms) only for the purpose of complying with applicable children's privacy statutes, but must include some useful functionality or entertainment value regardless of the user's age

**OR**

> Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be rejected

So my guess is that they think your registration is slightly *fishy*. I would suggest really making sure that the reasons for collecting that personal information are very visible to the Apple reviewers. They probably thought that your reasons for collecting a lot of info from the user is unnecessary for what your app does.

My recommendation is - take out what you don't really need and justify why you need what you're asking your users for and let Apple know in the notes for the reviewer.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot for the explanation!
May I ask you what do you think about the solution I suggested? Do you think it could be accepted or they'll see it just as a masking the problem?

Comment: I am afraid that could be slightly provocative. Obviously you don't need to provide registration in your app, as you may be targeting only certain group of people (maybe it's a service for existing customers, that already have a username/password). Then maybe you could add a demo account so they can easily review it. But putting a button that would tell them "register on the web" may not be the cleanest solution...

Comment: yeah i'm afraid of that too.. I think I'll give it a try and i'll explain the Review team why the registration form of the website requires all of those information and I hope they'll accept it. Thank you!